# Connecting 200 mm² high current cables

Tags: connector, high-current

I am working with high voltage (1000+ V) and high current (600+ A) heavy duty cables (200 mm² or more cross-section).

I am unable to find a good and clean way to join such cables.

I am on the look-out for options like quick-disconnect connectors, lug nuts or connectors from TE or Amphenol, but I could only find them for upto 50mm ² cables or 120A connectors.

Does anybody have experience working with such high current cables and could share their experience? That would be really helpful.

I also want to know about the possible methods to isolate such cables.

Comment: is this hobby or professional work?

Comment: Usually that's a split-nut connection <https://www.mcmaster.com/6921K66/> and rarely seen except on lightning rods...

Comment: Maybe check BEV fast chargers (now called supposedly "hyperchargers"). New ones are rated for 1000 V and a few 100 A, maybe their specs are sufficient, or there are series that are slightly beefier than this  to accomodate your needs.

Comment: @Whit3rd. That's a "split bolt", not a "split nut".

Answer (score 3):

Temporary (rental) high current cabling often uses [ITT Powerlock](https://www.ittcannon.com/powerlock).
You can get up to 300mm2 (with crimp).
However, it is common that when higher currents are required multiple cables are used. *(Taking the appropriate care of paralleling conductors course)*

[image: powerlock]

In contrast to the US Eatons suggested by Colintd, these are touch safe.
As they should be in 2024.

There is a large market in distribution boxes with this kind of terminals on the market.

Competing brands are POWERSYNTAX or Marechal SPeX.
Do not assume inter-brand or clone compatibility with these currents.

Comment: These are also good and well used connectors, though generally don't go to quite as large cables.  I was just about to add the same reference to my own answer, but you got there first!

Comment: thanks a lot for the help and suggestions

Comment: @colintd very often they run two cables per phase. When more is required the trusted ring terminal to busbar or G-clamps are used.

Comment: @Jeroen3 I have seen those setups, but I've also seen very heavy cables used in the US with the Eaton connectors.  Personally I'd use the Powerlocks as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Eaton [Roughneck](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/wiring-devices-and-connectivity/crouse-hinds/catalog-pages/crouse-hinds-roughneck-plugs-catalog-page.pdf) connectors might work for your application?

[image]

(Images from Eaton datasheet.)

They are good for cables in the target range (4/0 to 777mcm which is about 110mm\$^2\$ to 390mm\$^2\$). Rated upto 1135A at 1000V, and options for cable-cable and cable-busbar termination.

I've seen these connectors used for power connections to emergency "systems in shipping containers" when the power draw exceeds the normal IEC connectors.

Also worth considering the [PowerLock](https://www.ittcannon.com/powerlock) connectors (ITT original, but available from several suppliers).  They have a lower maximum current (upto 660A), but are touchproof (as noted in another answer).

[image]

You can also get premade [panels for terminating 3P+N+E.](https://docs.rs-online.com/53a8/0900766b810eb503.pdf)

[image]

(Images from ITT datasheets.)

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestion, I will check these connectors asap

Comment: Do let use know if this helps, and mark as answered if it is a solution.